# Mybatis type handler not fount

Tags: mybatis

I have:

```
<delete id="deleteTaskScheduling" parameterType="List">
        DELETE FROM ct_task_scheduling WHERE taskid IN
        <foreach collection="list" item="taskid" open="(" close=")" index="index" separator=",">
            #{taskid}
        </foreach>
    </delete>
```

and my POJO has taskid

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TaskDTO implements Serializable {

    private String taskid;
    ...
}
```

and I am passing List of TaskDTO to the interface:

```
List <TaskDTO> taskDTOs = new ArrayList <> ();
...
taskDAO.deleteTaskScheduling(taskDTOs);
```

but I am getting this exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Type handler was null on parameter mapping for property '__frch_taskid_0'. It was either not specified and/or could not be found for the javaType (com.mycompany.DTO.TaskDTO) : jdbcType (null) combination.] with root cause

Can someone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `<foreach />`, the variable specified in `item` represents each element of the list which is `TaskDTO` in your case.

```xml
<delete id="deleteTaskScheduling">
  DELETE FROM ct_task_scheduling WHERE taskid IN
  <foreach collection="list" item="x" open="(" close=")" separator=",">
    #{x.taskid}
  </foreach>
</delete>
```

Please read the documentation for the details.
https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html#foreach